# ERROR VertexFailedFast. Vertex failure triggered quick job abort

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am running a Data Lake - Analytics job and I getting the below error

> ERROR VertexFailedFast. Vertex failure triggered quick job abort.
>   Vertex failed: SV1_Extract[0][0] with error: Vertex user code error.
>   DESCRIPTION Vertex failed with a fail-fast error

Does anybody know why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cut off the error message part that actually tells why your extraction failed.

If you use a built-in extractor, it may be because you fail a data type cast, you have incorrect numbers of columns (for a variety of reasons) etc.

If you use a user defined extractor, it could be because of any C# runtime error that the user code generates.

Comment: Hi Michael , You said it right. I was using incorrect number of columns.

Comment: Hi Michael ,Can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030590/azure-net-sdk-error-fsopenstream-failed-with-error-0x83090aa2

Comment: For others who come across this, a quick check would be ensuring you have something like `USING Extractors.Csv(quoting:false, skipFirstNRows:1);` if you have a header row.