# Azure .Net SDK Error : FsOpenStream failed with error 0x83090aa2

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-data-lake

We are trying to download a file present in Data Lake Store. I have been following the below tutorial which uses .Net Azure SDk.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-analytics-get-started-net-sdk/

As we have already the file present in Azure Data Lake Store , I just added the code to download the file

```
FileCreateOpenAndAppendResponse beginOpenResponse = _dataLakeStoreFileSystemClient.FileSystem.BeginOpen("/XXXX/XXXX/test.csv", DataLakeStoreAccountName, new FileOpenParameters());
            FileOpenResponse openResponse = _dataLakeStoreFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Open(beginOpenResponse.Location);
```

But it's failing with the below error

> {"RemoteException":{"exception":"RuntimeException","message":"FsOpenStream
>   failed with error 0x83090aa2 (). 
>   [83271af3c3a14973ad7814e7d9d201f6]","javaClassName":"java.lang.RuntimeException"}}

While debugging we  inspected the **beginOpenResponse.Location** that been used in the second line code. It seems to the correct value as below

https://XXXXXXXX.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/XXXX/XXX/test.csv?op=OPEN&api-version=2015-10-01-preview&read=true

The error does not provide much information to track down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the store errors are currently *non-printable comment*. We are working on improving this.

According to my store developer, 0x83090aa2 is access check failed. Can you please check if you have access to the storage account and/or the path is correct?

Comment: can you please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128142/authorization-time-out-azure-data-lake-store-configuration-in-azure-data-facto