# Authorization Time Out : Azure Data Lake Store Configuration in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

We are moving the data from Azure Table Storage to Azure Data Lake Store with the help of Data Factory. As part of if I have added a linked service which connects to Azure Data Lake Store.

```
{
    "name": "AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "description": "",
        "hubName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
        "typeProperties": {
            "dataLakeStoreUri": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1",
            "authorization": "**********",
            "sessionId": "**********",
            "subscriptionId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
            "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

For this Azure Data Lake Store linked service there is an Authorize button. We Authorized and we are able to move the data successfully to Azure Data Lake Store.

But the problem is after some time the Authorization expiry occurs and the request becomes unauthorized. Then again I need to reauthorize the connection information.

I need to avoid this step, Authorizing the requesting everytime after the timeout. How can do it? Please share any useful links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Microsoft account to authorize the linked service. Due to that, the timeout of was happening frequently (less than a day).I was advised to use Azure Active Directory Account, which will not timeout for 90 days. I followed the instruction and the DataFactory is currently working fine without any timeout for the past one week.

Another advice I got was to use  Service Principal, ie authorize with Application registered in the Azure Active Directory rather that individual user account. I am yet to try this approach.